# WPF MaterialDesign Dialog Host

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I am building a WPF application and I would like to have custom MessageBox but I saw that is really tedious and I thought of using the DialogHost provided by MaterialDesign. The problem is that I can't get it to work the way I want it to so let me describe the current behaviour and the wanted one.

The current behaviour:

```
<materialDesign:ColorZone Grid.Column="1"
                                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  Mode="Light"
                                  Padding="16">
            <DockPanel>
                <materialDesign:DialogHost DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                    <Button x:Name="PowerButton"
                            ToolTip="{Binding PowerButtonToolTip, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=ButtonsResources}}"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}"
                            Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}">
                        <Button.CommandParameter>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="TODO" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                            Margin="0, 20, 0, 10">
                                    <Button Width="90"
                                            Height="30"
                                            Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"
                                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedButton}"
                                            Click="PowerButton_Click">
                                        OK
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button Width="90"
                                            Height="30"
                                            Margin="10, 0, 10, 0"
                                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedButton}"
                                            Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}">
                                        CANCEL
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.CommandParameter>
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Power" />
                    </Button>
                </materialDesign:DialogHost>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="MenuButton"
                                  Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignHamburgerToggleButton}" />
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="16 0 0 0"
                               Text="{Binding MainViewTitle, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=ViewsResources}}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </materialDesign:ColorZone>
```

What happens is that when I'm clicking the PowerButton the DialogHost appears with the structure from the Button.CommandParameter. The issue with this is that the window doesn't get "disabled" (getting a little black and unclickable) while the dialogue is on.

I saw that to achieve this behaviour I need to but all the content of the window inside the DialogHost. But is it really so or I am misunderstanding something? Their example ([see link](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/Dialogs.xaml)) isn't really helpful because there seem to be other things running in the background. Moreover, the command materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand of the button that is opening the "Topmost dialogue host" seems limited to me.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure your implementation is really correct, anyway this is not the way I do or the way the documentation does. Try to get  [to the demo](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/Dialogs.xaml) especially on the line 45 to have a perfect exemple and try to apply to your code. If you need morte precision i can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try something simple fo you to try at the first time.

The DialogHost is composed of two major parts

- First everything that is displayed into your DialogHost, this have to be into one block (StackPanel, Grid, DockPanel...) that is the content of your DialogHost.
- Second part is more like the context of your dialog, when you want to display it have to be somewhere to be displayed, another block (StackPanel, Grid, DockPanel...), the context is the place where your dialog will be once displayed, il will show centered and darken the rest of the block.

Now you have the main theory let's make a simple sample based on the sample given by the demo and your piece of code.

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
        <StackPanel Margin="16">
            <!-- HERE GOES YOUR CONTENT -->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" IsDefault="True"
                        Margin="0 8 8 0" Command="materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand">
                    <Button.CommandParameter>
                         <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
                     </Button.CommandParameter> 
                     ACCEPT
                 </Button>
                 <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                         IsCancel="True" Margin="0 8 8 0" 
                         Command="materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand">
                     <Button.CommandParameter>
                         <system:Boolean>False</system:Boolean>
                     </Button.CommandParameter>
                     CANCEL
                 </Button>
             </StackPanel>
         </StackPanel>
     </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
     <!-- START OF YOUR CONTEXT-->

     

     <!-- END OF YOUR CONTEXT -->
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

So now you have the basis that may be enough for you to start enjoying.

A little more, your context need to be large enough to display what you put on your DialogHost so you can't put a whole dialog around a button, it is better to make it around something bigger, as a first try you should try on a new page to test this context :

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Button x:Name="PowerButton" ToolTip="{Binding PowerButtonToolTip, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=ButtonsResources}}"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}"
      Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}">
</Grid>
```

The Buttons under the content are simply there if you desire to do an action, for example if the DialogHost is there for a modification or a choice where the user can say Yes or No then rename ACCEPT and CANCEL as you want. The "IsDefault" is there to make that it is this button that is considered as pressed if the user press Enter. Pressing a button automatically close the Dialog that is good to know.
And as the both ACCEPT and CANCEL are button you can affect a Click event that will be pretty useful for advanced using of the DialogHost.

Comment: What I tried to do is the SAMPLE 2: Pass View from the example provided by the Material Design. What gets me is that the specific dialog host that gets opened by pressing PASS VIEW blocks the entire window (line 107). That is the behaviour that I want and I don't get it on how they manage to do that because they don't have a dialogHost that wraps the whole Xaml Window.

Comment: First why do you want a DialogHost that is Window-Sized isn't that easier to make a page ? 
If you really want that you just have to put the DialogHost right after the <Window ...> and put the whole windows basic content on the context

Comment: What do you mean why? I already mentioned that I want it to behave like a message box, i.e. making my whole window not responsive while the dialogue host is running. And as you already mentioned, if I have to put it next to my <Window> tag and put the whole content in the context, then this element is really limited.

Comment: Ok, so just put it next to your <Window> it doesn't affect any of the responsiveness of the window. This component is far to be limited actually it is one of the most interesting. If you just want to display a message on your app maybe you should also look for the snackbar that is more suitable maybe